# PyCharm is not responding on Ctrl key shortcuts

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

```
Environment: XUbuntu 13.04, Java: Oracle 7 u40
PyCharm 3.0 Community Edition
```

Any shortcut which involves <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is not working. 
For example, I can Copy-Paste text using mouse or middle-button, but not via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
When I hover mouse in menu, I can see shortcut tooltip and Settings confirm that shortcut is correct. But it is not working.
Shortcuts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> work normally.

Other apps, for example, Aptana studio - which is Java and Eclipse-based works normally. All system applications work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button OK.

Comment: These tickets sounds similar: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111274 AND http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80613

Comment: Oh, thank you. I don't thought, but redoing layout setup did all the trick.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably IBus is messing with your Java keyboard shortcuts.
Just do

```
killall ibus-daemon
```

Comment: jammed pycharm for me on 14.04

Answer (score 17):

I was able to resolve my problem seemingly by rearranging my keyboard layouts on Debian, so that my English(US) keyboard was on top. I'm only putting this down as a answer because its a solution that is stuck in the comments section and not as an actual answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 running Dovark layout. Moving english to the first spot fixed me instantly. I was going crazy. Thanks!

Comment: I had OS X running with an Australian keyboard setting: & the lack of some option key choices was also driving me crazy. In particular the failure of the intention shortcut. Adding the US keyboard and making it the active one fixed the problem. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Finally! I had croatian keyboard layout as first. Moving en-us to the first spot fixed ctrl-slash in PyCharm 2016.3 and Kubuntu 16.10. for commenting and uncommentig multlines

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.04 with KDE it goes to System Settings > Keyboard > Layouts, tick "Configure layouts" and move "English (US)" on top. After that all hotkeys in Java products works well with IBus regardless of selected layout.

Answer (score 11):

If you have installed **Vim emulator**, make sure it's not interfering with *IDE shortcuts*.

1. Go to **settings** -> **Vim emulation**
2. Then assign **IDE** or **Vim** to any of the shortcuts you want.

Comment: They are crazy that it's turned on by default. :D
That happened to me.

Answer (score 9):

In case you are using Ubuntu, disable Vim Emulator in pyCharm:

**Tools > Vim Emulator**

Comment: Altho this is really not an advice to disable a tool you're using, this indeed caused my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Solution to the above problem is simple:

Turn off **Vim Emulation** in the **Tools** menu

Edit: I had the same problem, and this solved

Comment: please add the reasoning for your answer

Answer (score 3):

I entered to File-Settings-Keymap and then I changed keymap version from existing to VisualStudio and it started to work correctly.

Comment: For some reason the stupid IDE switched my layout to osX

Answer (score 2):

Thats probably because the keyboard layout opted during installation is either MAC OS X . I suggest you can try out different layouts.

You can select different layout
File>Settings>Keymap>Select one that is suitable for your  system

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue. Please navigate as below to make the ctrl, alt work as expected:

file >> setting >> keymap >> change to XWin

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting my computer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vim Emulation, it's possible that it's intercepting some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations. To see if this is the case you can go to Settings/Other Settings/Vim Emulation and switch the Handler dropdown from Vim to IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu) (worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04).

In my case, some PyCharm shortcuts were being shadowed by Ubuntu shortcuts, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, which opens the Settings window on PyCharm, but corresponds to the 'Toggle shaded state' shortcut on Ubuntu.

I simply disabled the Ubuntu shortcut and the corresponding PyCharm shortcut worked like a Charm (pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me: View > Quick Switch Scheme... > Keymap > Windows
My version of Pycharm: 2022.3 built on November 30, 2022

Comment: For those use Xubuntu: KDE

Answer (score 0):

On my mac, I fix this by unplugging and replugging in my keyboard.  Only mention it as I didn't see it here.